# Grafana: reduce tags shown

Tags: grafana

I've created a panel. The legend is shown as:

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of tags.

How could I decrease the number of tags or select only ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what to show using the "Legend" field.

You could use, for example, something like:

```
Legend = {{__name__}}{instance="{{instance}}"}
```

To get:

```
httpcomponents_httpclient_pool_total_connections{instance="10.128.4.38:8080}
httpcomponents_httpclient_pool_tootl_pending{instance="10.128.4.38:8080}
```

Or simply:

```
Legend = {{__name__}}({{instance}})
```

To get:

```
httpcomponents_httpclient_pool_total_connections(10.128.4.38:8080)
httpcomponents_httpclient_pool_tootl_pending(10.128.4.38:8080)
```